# how to let spring data mongodb to execute createIndexes before every test method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

A field of MongoDB Entity MyCardDO, explicitly set it to unique

```
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String uid;
```

and there is a `MyCardService` to crud MyCardDO, and there is a `MyCardServiceTest` to test `MyCardService`, there is a `add_repeat_uid_record_failed` inner MyCardServiceTest to test the uid cannot be duplicated,

```
    MyCardDO myCardDO1 = new MyCardDO();
    myCardDO1.setUid("1");
    myCardService.add(myCardDO1);

    try {
        MyCardDO myCardDO2 = new MyCardDO();
        myCardDO2.setUid("1");
        myCardService.add(myCardDO2);

        Assert.fail();
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        assertTrue(e.getMessage().contains("E11000 duplicate key error collection: opportunity-test.pro_mycard index: uid dup key: { : \"1\" }"));
    }
```

If I run this test method directly it's OK, but I run the whole `MyCardServiceTest` this method is failed, and from Wireshark I know the `createIndexes` only executed once, if dropped the collection it will not createIndexes again

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    mongoTemplate.dropCollection(MyCardDO.class);
}
```

So how to let spring to execute createIndexes before every test method? that is

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // how to auto execute createIndexes before every test method
    // prepare some test data
    myCardService.add(myCardDO1);

}
```

p.s.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,value={MyCardService.class}))
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import(SpringMongoConfig.class)
public class MyCardServiceTest {
    //...
}
```

Wireshark screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Final my resolution :

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), MyCardDO.class);
}
@AfterClass
public static void finalClean() {
    mongoTemplate.dropCollection(MyCardDO.class);
}
```

that is after finished every test method only delete all records and at final when the whole test class is finished to drop the collection.